# The value of textbox does not update in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, I have a textbox, and I want by clicking on ++, it increase by 1, but the value does not change by clicking, although I set setVal, Any idea

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

 function WidgeStar (){

    const [val, setVal ] = useState (20);
       
    return (
        <div>
            <div><input type="button" value="1" onclick = {() => setVal(16)} text="1" /></div>
            <div><input type="button" value="2" onclick = {() => setVal(16)} text="2" /></div>
            <div><input type="button" value="3" onclick = {() => setVal(16)} text="3" /></div>           
            <div><input type="button" value="++" onclick = {() => this.setVal(val-1)} /></div>
            <div><input type="button" value="--" onclick = {() => setVal(val-1)} /></div>       
            <div><input type="text" value= {val} /></div>
             
        </div>
    );
 } 
export default WidgeStar;
```

Comment: Could be as simple as changing onclick -> onClick. Also this.setVal is wrong. It's just setVal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onclick` to `onClick` - see "[Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)" from the React documentation. Also, you don't need to call `this.setVal`, just `setVal`. And if you want `++` to increment the value, you should use `val+1` instead of `val-1` (it looks like your code does the same thing for `++` and `--` at the moment):

```
<div><input type="button" value="++" onClick = {() => setVal(val+1)} /></div>
```

Comment: in react you also need set events in a camel case, like this onClick

Comment: Yesss, Change onclick to onClick and it worked, thanks a lot.